# Js drag&drop image/video upload with preview

Tags: javascript, image, video, drag-and-drop

My goal is to have a drag and drop upload box for videos AND images, that will populate the file in the exact shape and size of the box.

You can see the snippet here: http://jsfiddle.net/ELcf6/4/

Can't figure out, how to add the same functionality for video upload to the same box. Would appreciate any help.

Here's the snippet:

```js
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('filePhoto');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);

function handleImage(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        
        $('.uploader img').attr('src',event.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

```css
.uploader {position:relative; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:350px; background:#f3f3f3; border:2px dashed #e8e8e8;}

#filePhoto{
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    top:-50px;
    left:0;
    z-index:2;
    opacity:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.uploader img{
    position:absolute;
    width:302px;
    height:352px;
    top:-1px;
    left:-1px;
    z-index:1;
    border:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="uploader" onclick="$('#filePhoto').click()">
    click here or drag here your images for preview and set userprofile_picture data
    <img src=""/>
    <input type="file" name="userprofile_picture"  id="filePhoto" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so much a fix, as a suggestion, however as someone who had to make client side uploading before, I found using http://www.dropzonejs.com/ so much easier.

Comment: So since this is a suggestion and not fix/answer shouldn't this be posted as a comment and not a answer?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you are searching for is: **createObjectURL**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

However, the browser must support it.

Comment: Hey Jelle! Thanks so much! I'll check it out and see if it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you are trying to extract the image data from a video file this will not necessarily work. What you actually will need is a hidden video field and html5 canvas.When you drop the video file you populate the video source then play it through canvas as soon as you detect any image data you will be able to display it the same way you would the image. There's tons of answers on how to play video through canvas on StackOverflow and its not that difficult actually to put together.

Comment: Hi Vic, thank you for taking time leaving the comment! I'll look into it. Hopefully I can quickly figure it out

Comment: The easiest option I'd say would be when you are dropping video you actually populate the src of video field, seek to the middle and disable controls and apply the same styles.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your JSFiddle to kinda do what you wanted [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ELcf6/568/)
I tested it only in chrome it works. Update it to your needs.

```
function handleImage(e) {
    var filetype = imageLoader.files[0].type;
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (event) {
    if(filetype.indexOf("image") > -1){
    $('.uploader img').attr('src',event.target.result);
    }else if(filetype.indexOf("video") > -1){

    $('.uploader video')[0].src =reader.result; 
    }

}
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
```

}

On a footnote make sure you drop the compatible videos. Not all video files will show.

Comment: Hey Vic, thanks a million! It actually works!!! Awesome! However, is there a way of also playing the video in that window after upload you think?

Comment: UPDATE: I've tried to add it to my Wordpress, and it won't work, yet it works  on http://jsfiddle.net/ELcf6/568/ - it's driving me crrrraaazyyyy :(

Comment: Yes technically you should need to add autoplay param to your video element to play. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ELcf6/570/)

Comment: Also if you post a link to your WP (or pm me) site I might be able to help. But take into account that you aren't really uploading that file all it does it tries to play your local file.

Comment: To upload it you would need to generate a Blob from video file and upload it via Ajax to your site then reference the file that you just uploaded and play it from there.